# Why are key names stored in the document in MongodDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm curious about this quote from Kyle Banker's MongoDB In Action:

> It’s important to consider the length of the key names you choose, since key names are stored in the documents themselves. This contrasts with an RDBMS, where column names are always kept separate from the rows they refer to. So when using BSON, if you can live with dob in place of date_of_birth as a key name, you’ll save 10 bytes per document. That may not sound like much, but once you have a billion such documents, you’ll have saved nearly 10 GB of storage space just by using a shorter key name. This doesn’t mean you should go to unreasonable lengths to ensure small key names; be sensible. But if you expect massive amounts of data, economizing on key names will save space.

I am interested in the reason why this is not optimized on the database server side. Would a in-memory lookup table with all key names in the collection be too much of a performance penalty that is not worth the potential space savings?

Comment: a posted a similar comment to their JIRA system.. it looks like there's not enough interest for this feature (?)

Comment: I'm not requesting a feature here really, I am more interested in the reasoning for this particular design decision.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are referring to is often called "key compression"*. There are several reasons why it hasn't been implemented:

1. If you want it done, you can currently do it at the Application/ORM/ODM level quite easily.
2. It's not necessarily a performance** advantage in all cases — think collections with lots of key names, and/or key names that vary wildly between documents.
3. It might not provide a measurable performance** advantage at all until you have millions of documents.
4. If the server does it, the full key names still have to be transmitted over the network.
5. If compressed key names are transmitted over the network, then readability *really* suffers using the javascript console.
6. Compressing the entire JSON document <s>might offer</s> offers an even better performance advantage.

Like all features, there's a cost benefit analysis for implementing it, and (at least so far) other features have offered more "bang for the buck".

Full document compression is <s>[being considered][1] for a future MongoDB version.</s> available as of version 3.0 (see below)

* An in-memory lookup table for key names is basically a special case of LZW style compression — that's more or less what most compression algorithms do.

** Compression provides both a space advantage and a performance advantage. Smaller documents means that more documents can be read per IO, which means that in a system with fixed IO, more documents per second can be read.

### Update

MongoDB versions 3.0 and up now have full document compression capability with the [WiredTiger](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/storage/#wiredtiger-storage-engine) storage engine.

Two compression algorithms are available: [snappy](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/), and [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/). The intent is for snappy to be the best choice for all-around performance, and for zlib to be the best choice for maximum storage capacity.

In my personal (non-scientific, but related to a commercial project) experimentation, snappy compression (we didn't evaluate zlib) offered significantly improved storage density at no noticeable net performance cost. In fact, there was slightly better performance in some cases, roughly in line with my previous comments/predictions.

Comment: 1 + 5 -> if you do it on the application level, the javascript console becomes quite useless. also it's a PITA if you connect from multiple apps (with different languages)

Comment: "An in-memory lookup table for key names is basically a special case of LZW style compression" - the problem with this is that compression is *per document*. there is a lot of repetition in the collection, but not much in a document.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: doing it at the collection level has challenges too — what if you add a document with 10000 keys, and then delete it? You need garbage collection in the per collection lookup table.

Comment: I think none of us suggests this should be the default behavior. just an option.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: sure, but these are things that need to be thought of when you implement a feature like this. Nobody wants to handle a support call for "I added key compression, and now everything is super slow".

Comment: I really like that answer, thanks. But shouldn't "performance advantage" in 2 and 3 be "space advantage"? I'd recon it would be a bit slower, but save bytes as Banker suggested.

Comment: Oh well it could of course be a performance advantage on the transmission level, but Banker was really only talking about memory usage there.

Comment: @c089: It does provide a space advantage, but space actually also means performance. I've added an extra footnote to the answer to make it clearer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

I believe one of the original reasons behind storing the key names with the documents is to allow a more easily scalable [schema-less](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/119945109/why-schemaless) database.  Each document is self-contained to a greater extent, in that if you move the document to another server (for example, via replication or sharding) you can index the contents of the document without having to reference separate or centralized metadata such as a mapping of key names to more compact key IDs.

Since there is no enforced schema for a MongoDB collection, the field names can potentially be different for every document in the same collection. In a [sharded](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) environment, inserts to each shard are (intentionally) independent so at a document level the raw data could end up differing unless the key mapping was able to be consistent per shard.

Depending on your use case, the key names may or may not consume a significant amount of space relative to the accompanying data.  You could always workaround the storage concern from the application / ODM implementation by mapping YourFriendlyKeyNames to shorter DB key equivalents.

There is an open MongoDB Jira issue and some further discussion to [have the server tokenize field names](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-863), which you can vote on to help prioritize including this feature in a future release.

MongoDB's current design goals include performance with dynamic schemas, replication & high availability, auto-sharding, and in-place updates .. with one potential tradeoff being some extra disk usage.

Answer (score 1):

Having to look this up within the database for each and every query would be a serious penalty.
Most drivers allow you to specify ElementName, so that `MyLongButReadablePropertyName` in your domain model becomes `mlbrpn` in mongodb.

Therefore, when you query in your application, it's the application that transforms the query that would of been:

```
db.myCollection.find({"MyLongButReadablePropertyName" : "some value"})
```

into

```
db.myCollection.find({"mlbrpn" : "some value"})
```

Efficient drivers, like the C# driver cache this mapping, so it doesn't need to look this up for each and every query.

Coming back to the title of your question:

> Why are key names stored in the document in MongodDB

This is the only way documents can be searched?
Without the key names stored , there'd be no key to search on.

Hope this helps

Comment: "a serious penalty" - oh, come on... it's an O(1) lookup per key.

Comment: O(1) a million times is still a million more queries than you need to do.

Comment: ... i do however agree with the jira link @Stennie posted - would be nice if the tokenization could happen server side. A minor point though, since I do this in code with the drivers.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the title of the question was a bit unfortunate (it was derived from the quote). Feel free to edit if you can come up with something better.