# Simple where query returns no results with mongomapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a database with some data in a rails project with mongomapper.

In the rails console:

```
[1] pry(main)> MyObject.first
=> #<MyObject _id: BSON::ObjectId('525e6a9156c02c22de000002'), my_field: 1, 
...

[2] pry(main)> MyObject.where(my_field: 1).all
=> []
[3] pry(main)> MyObject.where(my_field: 1.to_s).all
=> []
[4] pry(main)> MyObject.where(my_field: "1").all
=> []
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Its because of abbr

In my model:

```
key :my_field, String, required: true, abbr: :mf
```

Correct query:

```
[5] pry(main)> MyObject.where(mf: "1").all
=> [#<MyObject _id: BSON::ObjectId('525e6a9156c02c22de000002'), my_field: 1, 
...
```

Imho, this abbr thing is crazy

It's a [super leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) to deal with the fact that [key names stored in the document in MongodDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11429804/why-are-key-names-stored-in-the-document-in-mongoddb).

Comment: if the ruby driver doesn't support aliasing, make sure you're choosing the right tradeoff here. If the collection has a million documents and you're saving 40 bytes each, that's a mere 40MB you're saving, not worth the troublem IMHO.

Comment: Regarding the leaky abstraction: I beg to differ. It's not an abstraction at all. You're *assuming* that objects in a DB should all have the same format (as in a table), but MongoDB is a *document store* where the assumption doesn't hold. But that's because it's *not* putting an abstraction on the schema unlike other dbs. The culprit here is the ruby driver, which doesn't support the mapping in the queries.

Comment: The problem that I have is that I have to *remember* to 2 names in my head all the time. And depending of where I am, I have to *think* about which one to use...

Comment: Yes, but that was *your* choice. Nobody forces you to use aliases. As usual, the problem arises from performance concerns. On the coding side, you could extend the driver to support you in this matter. The C# driver, for instance, offers this feature. This won't help when using the DB shell. Then again, make sure you really need the alias, you're merely saving a couple of bytes.